# ImageIcon + Closing on Clicking a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, joptionpane, imageicon

I'm trying to get the PayPal logo come up when you click the 'rightbutton' is clicked. Unfortunately, all that shows is the default Java logo with the cup of coffee and a pen.

Also, how can I make it so once you click "OK" or "Cancel" it closes the JOptionPane, currently, when you click "OK" nothing happens, it keeps giving you the "OK" / "Cancel" option.

```
    rightbutton = new JButton("Right.");
    add(rightbutton);
    rightbutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    //what do we want to happen when we
                    //click the button
                    final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Scr3am\\Desktop\\paypal.jpg");
                    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Congratulations, you clicked the button.", "Congrats", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[] { panel }, icon);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you trying to use a JOptionPane where a JFrame will be more useful.

A JOptionPane is simply used as an information or error message where as a JFrame is for everything else.

Solution:

Make a JFrame, add a JLabel to it and set it as an image with JLabel.setImage("Directory");

and then add two buttons, Ok and Cancel.

I would Suggest netbeans JFrame form editor.

And if you are still new to java try downloading some examples and working from them and also try getting a book on java programming.

Good luck.